# Algebraic Topology chain maps

Tags: algebraic-topology

I came across the following statement in a textbook I am reading, and I was wondering what is meant by the abelian group of homotopy classes of chain maps. Could you help me out?

Thanks

Comment: You should say what textbook it is so an answer at the appropriate level can be given. Are you just learning about singular homology or chain complexes in general?

Comment: I really just want to know what the abelian group of homotopy classes of chain maps looks like.  Is it under addition?

Comment: Yes, chains have an additive structure, so $f + g$ makes sense, and on the level of homotopy classes we have $[f] + [g] = [f + g]$.